# Can you have background-image: linear-gradient( to center...);

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, red, blue);`

but I want the `to bottom` to be `to center` but it does not work.

wright, now it looks like this

[image: 1]

I want it to look like this

[image: 2]

Does anyone know how to do this pleas help me?

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing is a classic border:

```css
.box {
  border:40px solid blue;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

But I suspect you want a color fading so what you want is a `radial-gradient`

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-side,red,blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or maybe like below:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red, blue);
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, red, blue);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or like this:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: 
     linear-gradient(to top right   , red, blue) top right,
     linear-gradient(to top left    , red, blue) top left ,
     linear-gradient(to bottom left , red, blue) bottom left,
     linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, blue) bottom right;
  background-size:50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Also using `box-shadow`

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 35px blue inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this.

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background:
      linear-gradient(90deg, blue, rgba(0,255,0,0) 30%),
      linear-gradient(180deg, blue, rgba(0,0,255,0) 30%),
      linear-gradient(0deg, blue, rgba(0,255,0,0) 30%),
      linear-gradient(270deg, blue, rgba(0,0,255,0) 30%),
      linear-gradient(0deg, blue, red, red 50%),
      linear-gradient(90deg, blue, red, red 50%),
      linear-gradient(180deg, blue, red, red 50%),
      linear-gradient(270deg, blue, red, red 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to utilize multiple background gradients:

```css
.item {
  --outerColor: blue;
  --innerColor: red;
  
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: var(--innerColor);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--outerColor) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, var(--outerColor) 75%), linear-gradient(to right, var(--outerColor) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, var(--outerColor) 75%);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

---

Here's how it works:

### Step 1: Make pure red background:

```css
.item {
  --innerColor: red;
  
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: var(--innerColor);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

### Step 2: Add horizontal stripe

```css
.item {
  --outerColor: blue;
  --innerColor: red;
  
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: var(--innerColor);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--outerColor) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, var(--outerColor) 75%);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

### Step 3: Add vertical stripe

```css
.item {
  --outerColor: blue;
  --innerColor: red;
  
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: var(--innerColor);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--outerColor) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, var(--outerColor) 75%), linear-gradient(to right, var(--outerColor) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, var(--outerColor) 75%);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```